# I need a function to delete certain characters from a char array in c++ without using any index

Tags: c++, arrays, string, c++11, char

for example:
if the user enters :
**( 23+22+43)**

I want the function to do exactly the following :

```
for(int i =0; i <strlen(x);i ++)
{
   if (x[i]=='+')
   {
     deletfunc(x[i]);
     deletfunc(x[i+1]);
     cout<<x;
   }
}
```

so that the output will be **(2323)**

without using index ----> without knowing the exact number of the char in the array for example I couldn't say deletefunc[3] , I don't know if + is the 3rd or 4rth or 2nd element and so on and the + maybe repeated more than once.

Please if anyone can help I had been trying do this task for 4 days now

Comment: Put the string in a `std::string`. It has a [`erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) member function which does exactly what you seem to want `deletfunc` to do. I have no idea though what "_without using any index_" is supposed to mean.

Comment: And after 4 days of constant debugging you should put this down and get some sleep, dude. Today is not a good day to die.

Comment: without using index ----> without knowing the exact number of the char in the array for example I couldn't say deletefunc[3] , I don't know if + is the 3rd or 4rth or 2nd element and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when working with a C style string and the instructor says, "No indexes!" they want you to use a pointer.

Here is one way you could use a pointer

```
char * p = x; // point p at start of array x
while (*p) // loop until p points to the null terminator - the end of the string
{
    if (*p=='+') // if value at p is +
    {
        deletfunc(p - x); // distance between p and x is index
        if (*(p+1)) // make sure there is a p+1 to erase
        {
            deletfunc(p+1 - x); 
        }
    }
    p++; // advance pointer to next character in array x
}
cout << x; // print revised string
```